# replace two separate words in a matched string sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

Consider the following input string.

```
PLOG_NFET_SLVT nf=3 ng=1 nl=20n
```

Output

```
PLOG_NFET_LVT nf=3 ng=1 nl=14n
```

Note: 1st and last word are replaced. Also in between data varies. So I can not have a constant pattern. I tried using below command.

```
sed -i 's/PLOG.*FET_SLVT.*nl=20n/PLOG.*FET_LVT.*nl=14n/g' file
```

and output is :

```
PLOG.*FET_LVT.*nl=14n
```

Any help?

Comment: What's the operation on the 20n to 14n?

Comment: it's a fixed change. SLVT --> LVT    and 20-->14

Comment: See my method, do 2 subs instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group in the search pattern and add the backreference (`\1` or `\2`) to the replace pattern:

```
sed 's/PLOG_\([A-Z]\)FET_SLVT \(.*\) nl=20n/PLOG_\1FET_LVT \2 nl=14n/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 sed -i 's/^PLOG_NFET_SLVT/PLOG_NFET_LVT/g;s/20n$/14n/g' file
```

- search for the patter **starts** with `PLOG_NFET_SLVT` and replace with `PLOG_NFET_LVT`
- and search for the patter **ends** with `20n` and replace with `14n`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/SLVT/LVT/;s/20n/14n/'
```

#### Example

```
$ echo "PLOG_NFET_SLVT nf=3 ng=1 nl=20n" | sed 's/SLVT/LVT/;s/20n/14n/'
PLOG_NFET_LVT nf=3 ng=1 nl=14n
```

Comment: I guess these are two separate commands. But here I need both the substitutions on the same string. It's  "AND" replacement. Thanks

Comment: This is a AND replacement, it's done on 1 string.

Comment: @RoopakVasa Every `sed` command is always applied to all lines (unless the commands branches to another part of a script or explicitly continues with the next line or quits).

Comment: @slm OP's concern are genuine. Only those finfets whose model names equal "PLOG_NFET_SVT" and out if these, which have a channel length of 20nm should be shrinked to 14nm. What your sed code would do is much more than that.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - sigh...there are concerns wrt the regex, but easily addressed. The OP provides barely any sample data or requirements, this solves the issue and does not have any issues w/ doing too much or too little based on what he/she has shown. Instead of focusing on the ppl giving too general an A'er, you should be directing your critiques to the OP who isn't specifying his/her Q with enough data or requirements.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - I can come up w/ many data examples that break the accepted A'er + others too, that isn't the point here, these Q's need to be more strictly asked, if there are requirements, they should be stating them, not the A'ers.

Comment: @slm i was solving  similar problem of netlist manipulation and was looking it at from that angle.not  meant s a critique.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - none taken. 8-).